# How to configure monit, check process to start program when only filesystem is available?

Tags: monit

I want monit to check specific process and start it only when the depending filesystem is available.

```
check process Tomcat with pidfile /path/to/tomcat/TOMCAT.PID 
        depends on abc
        start program = "../scripts/start_tomcat.sh"
        stop program = "../scripts/stop_tomcat.sh  -force"

check filesystem abc with path /path/to/abc
        if does not exist then restart
```

In that above configuration, when filesystem goes down, monit is repeatedly start and stop the tomcat, which makes 8080 port in listen all the time. I want to make that start program runs only when filesystem is available. Not repeatedly start and stop it.

Comment: Write your own script. Why bother with monit?

Comment: Why would the filesystem go down? Can you provide more detail on what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Here, 
you defined *restart* as action on the *filesystem*, so when the file does not exist, it will mostly propagate the *restart* action to all depending 'check' rule as state in the documentation:

> If a service is restarted, it will first stop any active services that depend on it and after it is started, start all depending services that were active before the restart again.

As state by someone else previously, why would the filesystem goes down ? If that's a mounted directory, best would be to take action to mount again the file system with a custom '*exec* action in the rule for the filesystem and let monit start the tomcat through the dependency management rule.

More details at : https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-DEPENDENCIES